# Google Table Chart: Wrote a calculation function, adds the previously click cells instead of the current cells

Tags: javascript, function, google-visualization

I wrote a function that calculates the total number in the specified cells**(Line 522 in JScode)**, then takes that number and writes it in a  tag**(line 438 is where that function starts)**.

The problem is its calculating the number before its suppose to. I know that what kind of happen, but I'm not quite sure how to correct it. Also Im trying to get the function to run when the page loads, so the it calculates the table cells from the start

http://jsfiddle.net/dcw2qq/jejcwz0f/1/

```
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});




  function drawDashboard() {




    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

     data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
     data.addColumn('string', 'Description');
     data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');



     data.addRows([
            [new Date(2010, 6, 13),'CRATE AND BARREL #344', 'Merchandise',{v: 232.00, f: '$232.00'}],
          [new Date(2010, 4, 4),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
          [new Date(2010, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 56.23, f: '$56.23'}],
          [new Date(2010, 9, 6),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 24.50, f: '$24.50'}],
          [new Date(2010, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
          [new Date(2010, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 645.67, f: '$645.67'}],
          [new Date(2010, 5, 23),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
          [new Date(2010, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 45.03, f: '$45.03'}],
          [new Date(2010, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 56.00, f: '$56.00'}],
          [new Date(2010, 6, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
          [new Date(2010, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 876.23, f: '$876.23'}],
          [new Date(2010, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.34, f: '$19.34'}],
          [new Date(2010, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
          [new Date(2010, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 309.76, f: '$309.76'}],
          [new Date(2010, 3, 4),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 3.21, f: '$3.21'}],
          [new Date(2010, 10, 13),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
          [new Date(2010, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 923.55, f: '$923.55'}],
          [new Date(2010, 7, 24),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.56, f: '$98.56'}],
          [new Date(2010, 3, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
          [new Date(2010, 9, 16),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 456.12, f: '$456.12'}],

          [new Date(2011, 6, 16),'CRATE AND BARREL #644', 'Merchandise',{v: 292.00, f: '$292.00'}],
          [new Date(2011, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
          [new Date(2011, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 56.26, f: '$56.26'}],
          [new Date(2011, 9, 6),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
          [new Date(2011, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
          [new Date(2011, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 685.67, f: '$685.67'}],
          [new Date(2011, 5, 26),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
          [new Date(2011, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.06, f: '$85.06'}],
          [new Date(2011, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 56.00, f: '$56.00'}],
          [new Date(2011, 6, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
          [new Date(2011, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 876.26, f: '$876.26'}],
          [new Date(2011, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.68, f: '$19.68'}],
          [new Date(2011, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
          [new Date(2011, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 609.76, f: '$609.76'}],
          [new Date(2011, 6, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 6.21, f: '$6.21'}],
          [new Date(2011, 10, 16),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
          [new Date(2011, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 926.55, f: '$926.55'}],
          [new Date(2011, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.56, f: '$98.56'}],
          [new Date(2011, 6, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
          [new Date(2011, 9, 16),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 856.12, f: '$856.12'}],

          [new Date(2012, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 292.00, f: '$292.00'}],
          [new Date(2012, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
          [new Date(2012, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
          [new Date(2012, 9, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
          [new Date(2012, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
          [new Date(2012, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 285.27, f: '$285.27'}],
          [new Date(2012, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
          [new Date(2012, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.02, f: '$85.02'}],
          [new Date(2012, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 872.22, f: '$872.22'}],
          [new Date(2012, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.28, f: '$19.28'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
          [new Date(2012, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 209.72, f: '$209.72'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
          [new Date(2012, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 922.55, f: '$922.55'}],
          [new Date(2012, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.52, f: '$98.52'}],
          [new Date(2012, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
          [new Date(2012, 9, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 852.12, f: '$852.12'}],

          [new Date(2013, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 222.00, f: '$222.00'}],
          [new Date(2013, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.22, f: '$252.22'}],
          [new Date(2013, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
          [new Date(2013, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
          [new Date(2013, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 285.27, f: '$285.27'}],
          [new Date(2013, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
          [new Date(2013, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.02, f: '$85.02'}],
          [new Date(2013, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 102.78, f: '$102.78'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 872.22, f: '$872.22'}],
          [new Date(2013, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 12.28, f: '$12.28'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
          [new Date(2013, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 202.72, f: '$202.72'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
          [new Date(2013, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 222.55, f: '$222.55'}],
          [new Date(2013, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 28.52, f: '$28.52'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
          [new Date(2013, 2, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 852.12, f: '$852.12'}],

          [new Date(2014, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 222.00, f: '$222.00'}],
          [new Date(2014, 8, 3),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.22, f: '$252.22'}],
          [new Date(2014, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 23.50, f: '$23.50'}],
          [new Date(2014, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 13.00, f: '$13.00'}],
          [new Date(2014, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 235.27, f: '$235.27'}],
          [new Date(2014, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
          [new Date(2014, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 35.02, f: '$35.02'}],
          [new Date(2014, 0, 3),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 102.73, f: '$102.73'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 372.22, f: '$372.22'}],
          [new Date(2014, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 12.23, f: '$12.23'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
          [new Date(2014, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 202.72, f: '$202.72'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 3),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
          [new Date(2014, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.37, f: '$25.37'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 222.55, f: '$222.55'}],
          [new Date(2014, 7, 23),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 23.52, f: '$23.52'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
          [new Date(2014, 2, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 352.12, f: '$352.12'}]


    ]);


    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0,1,{calc: mas,type: 'string',label:'Category'},3])
          function mas(view2,row) {
              var a = view2.getValue(row,2);
              return a;
          }




var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
  'containerId': 'filter_div',
  'options': {
     'filterColumnLabel': 'Date',
     'ui': { 'format': { 'pattern': 'yyyy' } },
  }
});


var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'control2',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Category',
    'filterColumnIndex':2,
    'ui': {
    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  },
 //'state': {'selectedValues': ['Gas/Automotive', 'Lodging','Merchandise']}
});



var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'control3',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Category',
    'filterColumnIndex':1,
    'ui': {
    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  },
 //'state': {'selectedValues': ['Gas/Automotive', 'Lodging','Merchandise']}
});


    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',


      'options': {
        'pieHole':.5,
        //'colors':['#639fd7','#668ba5','#66bba4','#67e6a3','#0cc4aa','#0bbde3','#0f9dd4','#2e8acc'],
        'slices': {
            0: {color: '#f1969d'},
            1: {color: '#f87f4a'},
            2: {color: '#f7b549'},
            3: {color: '#f9e848'},
            4: {color: '#79c04f'},
            5: {color: '#78b8bc'},
            6: {color: '#7c9496'},
            7: {color: '#9f7f82'},
             },
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'pieSliceBorderColor': 'transparent',

        'chartArea':{
            'left':130,
            'top':1,
            //'width':1000,
            'height':300,
            'backgroundColor':'transparent',
          },  
        //'width': 700,
        'height': 290,
        'is3D':false,
        'pieSliceText':'none',


        'legend':{
            'position': 'right',
            'alignment':'center',
            'textStyle': {
                'color': '#262626',
                'fontSize': 16
                }
            }

      }
    });


    var pieChart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div2',
      'options': {
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'pieSliceBorderColor': 'transparent',
        'pieHole':.25,
        //'colors':['#639fd7','#668ba5','#66bba4','#67e6a3','#0cc4aa','#0bbde3','#0f9dd4','#2e8acc'],
        'slices': {
            0: {color: '#f1969d'},
            1: {color: '#f87f4a'},
            2: {color: '#f7b549'},
            3: {color: '#f9e848'},
            4: {color: '#79c04f'},
            5: {color: '#78b8bc'},
            6: {color: '#7c9496'},
            7: {color: '#9f7f82'},
             },
        'chartArea':{
            'left':130,
            'top':1,
            //'width':1000,
            'height':300,
            'backgroundColor':'transparent',
          },  
        //'width': 700,
        'height': 290,
        'is3D':false,
        'pieSliceText':'none',
        'legend':{
            'position': 'right',
            'alignment':'center',
            'textStyle': {
                'color': '#262626',
                'fontSize': 16
                }
            }

      }
    });     




    var tableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'table_div',
      options: {

                alternatingRowStyle:false,
                cssClassNames:{
                        headerRow: 'headerRow',
                        hoverTableRow: 'hoverTableRow',
                        tableRow:'tableRow',
                        oddTableRow:'oddTableRow',
                        selectedTableRow:'selectedTableRow',
                        headerCell:'headerCell',
                        tableCell:'tableCell',
                        rowNumberCell:'rowNumberCell' 
                }


      }
    });















               function selectHandler() {

                    var dt = tableChart.getDataTable();
                      var catGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                      type:'string',
                                      label:dt.getColumnLabel(2),
                                      column: 2,



                                      }],[{
                                          type: 'number',
                                          label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                          column: 3,                                                
                                          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                          }
                                      ]);
                      //alert('The user selected ' + catGroup.getValue(pieChart.getChart().getSelection()[0].row,0));
                      var categoryPicked = catGroup.getValue(pieChart.getChart().getSelection()[0].row,0);
                      categoryPicker.setState({'selectedValues':[categoryPicked]});
                      $('.mainPieChart').toggleClass('hide');
                      $('.secondaryPieChart').toggleClass('hide');
                      $('span.title').text(categoryPicked);
                      categoryPicker.draw();

                }


                function updatePieCharts() {
                     var dt = tableChart.getDataTable();




                     var catGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                      type:'string',
                                      label:dt.getColumnLabel(2),
                                      column: 2,



                                      }],[{
                                          type: 'number',
                                          label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                          column: 3,                                                
                                          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                          }
                                      ]);
                                      pieChart.setDataTable(catGroup);
                                      formatter.format(catGroup, 1);                    
                                      pieChart.draw();

                    var catGroup2 = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                      type:'string',
                                      label:dt.getColumnLabel(1),
                                      column: 1,



                                      }],[{
                                          type: 'number',
                                          label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                          column: 3,                                                
                                          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                          }
                                      ]);
                                      pieChart2.setDataTable(catGroup2);
                                      formatter.format(catGroup2, 1);                   
                                      pieChart2.draw();

                }
```

////////////CALLING FUNCTION EVERY TIME PIESLICE IS CLICKED DO THIS
google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', selectHandler);

/////////////CALLING FUNCTION  "ready" event handler on the TABLEChart to aggregate the data for the PieCharts
google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', updatePieCharts);

/////////////CALLING FUNCTION  "ready" event handler on the Updates the Total in the heading.
google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', timeFrameHeadingNumber);

```
    function changeRangeOf(e,days) {

        //setActiveState();
        var timeframe = e
        $('.chart-nav button.btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#changeRange'+timeframe).addClass('active');


        //Header Updater
        var timeframeHeading = $('#changeRange'+timeframe).html();
        $('.dateRangeLabel').text(timeframeHeading);



        //setPieChart Range();
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const monthLength = (24*(days)) * 60 * 60 * 1000;       
        var ago = new Date(today.getTime() - monthLength);

        //Redraw Pie Chart();           
        dateRangeSlider.setState({lowValue: ago, highValue: today});
        dateRangeSlider.draw();

        $('.totalHeadingNumber').text(timeFrameHeadingNumber());





    }


    function timeFrameHeadingNumber(){
        var totalAmt = 0;
        $('td.google-visualization-table-td-number').each(function() {
                                var actualValue = Number($(this).text().replace('$',''));   
                                totalAmt = totalAmt + actualValue;                              



                                }); 

        return '$'+totalAmt.toFixed(2);
    }


     $("#changeRangeMo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('Mo',30)});
     $("#changeRange3Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('3Mo',90)});
     $("#changeRange6Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('6Mo',180)}); 
     $("#changeRange12Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('12Mo',365)}); 
     $("#changeRange24Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('24Mo',730)}); 
     $("#changeRange36Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('36Mo',1095)}); 
     $("#changeRange48Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('48Mo',1460)});
     $("#changeRangeYTD").click(function(){changeRangeOf('YTD',9999)})

     // Create a dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
    // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
    // given the chosen slider range.
    dashboard.bind([dateRangeSlider,categoryPicker,categoryPicker2],tableChart);





        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
                          {prefix: '$',fractionDigits: 2});
                            formatter.format(data,3); // Apply formatter to second column

        var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: " MM/dd/yyyy"});
        formatter_short.format(data, 0);



    // Draw the dashboard using the Data View Created early in the code.

    dashboard.draw(view);

    $(document).ready(function(){   


    function timeFrameHeadingNumberOnLoad(){
        var totalAmt = 0;
        $('td.google-visualization-table-td-number').each(function() {
                                var actualValue = Number($(this).text().replace('$',''));   
                                totalAmt = totalAmt + actualValue;                              



                                }); 

        return '$'+totalAmt.toFixed(2);
    }
```

});

```
  }
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
```

thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Code Lines to look at in particular are now LINE 404 function changeRangeOf & Line 437 function timeFrameHeadingNumber()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this approach.  First, you are creating a document ready event handler inside the callback from the google loader, which will likely be called after document ready fires, thus the ready event handler will never fire.  Second, you are calculating the values from the HTML immediately after initiating a redraw, so the table's contents have not changed yet (or are in the process of being removed), as the redraw is asynchronous.  You would need to use a "ready" event handler for the Table to get the correct values from the Table, but fortunately, you do not need to fetch this data from HTML at all.  There is a much simpler solution:

```
function setTimeFrameHeading () {
    var dt = tableChart.getDataTable();
    var totalAmt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dt.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        totalAmt += dt.getValue(i, 3);
    }
    var totalStr = formatter.formatValue(totalAmt);
    $('.totalHeadingNumber').text(totalStr);
}
```

Use this as the callback from the Table's "ready" event:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', setTimeFrameHeading);
```

and get rid of all the other code that deals with calculating the total.

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/jejcwz0f/2/

Comment: Thank you. that worked like a charm, and I now I have better understanding of the googleAPI. Thanks again.